# React JS - Event Handler in a dynamic list

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, this, eventhandler

I'm bringing a API s' content based on a dynamic list and I'm trying to apply a mouserEnter on each li. The event results by toggling content in the each list item. The event is working but it is toggling content in all the list items all at once, but I want it to toggle only the content that matches with the list item that is receiving the mouseEnter.

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Dribbble extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
   
    this.state = { 
      work: [],  
      hover: false      
    }; 
    
    this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this);
    
  }  

  handleMouseEnter(){
    this.setState({ hover: true })
  }

  handleMouseLeave(){
    this.setState({ hover: false })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ShotList();
  }

  ShotList() {
    return $.getJSON('https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots?per_page=3&access_token=41ff524ebca5e8d0bf5d6f9f2c611c1b0d224a1975ce37579326872c1e7900b4&callback=?')
      .then((resp) => {
        this.setState({ work: resp.data.reverse() });
      });
  } 

  render() {  
    
    const works = this.state.work.map((val, i) => {    
     
     return <li key={i} className="box"          
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}        
          >    
          {!this.state.hover ?     
            <div>
              <img className="cover" src={val.images.normal} />
              <div className="bar">
                <h2>{val.title}</h2>
                <span>{val.views_count}</span>
                <i className="fa fa-eye fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 
          : null} 
          {this.state.hover ?
            <div>
              <h3>{val.user.name}</h3>
              <img className="avatar img-circle" src={val.user.avatar_url}/>
              <p>{val.description}</p>              
            </div>
           :
           null
          }           
        </li>  
    });    

    return <ul>{works}</ul>
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your example, firstly as @aherriot states you should move the `ul` outside the map.

Next i would set `this.state.hover` to be the `id` of the `item` being hovered over on `onMouseEnter`.

The below snippet shows a basic example of this working that should be easy enough to adapt to your code.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: [{id: 1, name: 'Fred'}, {id: 2, name: 'Albert'}, {id: 3, name: 'Jane'}],
      hover: false,
    }
    
    this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this);
    this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleMouseEnter(id){
    console.log(`handleMouseEnter this.setState({ hover: ${id} })`);
    this.setState({ hover: id })
  }

  handleMouseLeave(){
    console.log('handleMouseLeave this.setState({ hover: false })');
    this.setState({ hover: false })
  }
  
  renderItem(item, index) {
    let content = [];
    content.push(
      <span>ID: {item.id}, Name: {item.name}</span>
    );
    
    if(this.state.hover === item.id) {
      console.log('display " - hovering" for item id: ' + item.id);
      content.push(
        <span> - hovering</span>
      );
    }
    
    return (
      <li key={item.id}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter(item.id)}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
      >
        {content}
      </li>
    )
  }
  
  render() {
    return <ul>
        {this.state.items.map(this.renderItem)}
    </ul>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain me better? Your example is a little different from mine. Give me more clues, please.

Comment: I am a beginner in React JS

Comment: The difference is that @Purgatory is not just tracking whether or not something is hovered, they are tracking the id of specific "work" that is being hovered. That way, when you map over the array, you check for each one if its `id` matches the hovered id, and make a decision on what to render based on that.

Comment: @claudiobitar I have added some `console.log` so you can see where things are happening. Unfortunately, I am not sure how I can make this any clearer.

Comment: Where do I enter this value: 'this.state.hover' ? and how do I attach this to the id? I'm very beginner in React.

Comment: @claudiobitar You can see I am doing it here `onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter(item.id)}` then inside the `handleMouseEnter` function I am doing `this.setState({ hover: id })`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should move the `<ul>` tag outside of `this.state.work.map` You only want one `<ul>` to show up, not one for each element.

You can place it at the bottom inside your div tag instead: `return (<div><ul>{works}</ul></div>)`